# Update Info Passed to Dialog

Tags: angular

I have a component that when clicked on, fetches data, receives it and opens up a modal and passes this data into it.

Whilst the modal is still open, I make further requests for additional data.

How do I pass the new data into the already open modal?

This is the code that fetches and opens the dialog

```
updateSomeData() {
  // fetch additional data
}

openDialog() {
 this.cqohs.fetchData(this.itemSelected).subscribe(({ data }: any) => {
  this.dialog.open(DialogComponent,
    {
      data: {
        a: this.someData,
        b: this.updateSomeData
      }
    });
```

This code opens up and passes the data correctly to the dialog and in the dialog component itself, based on some condition, I call the function, `b`, to get the additional data, which I am expecting to be forwarded back into the dialog but that is not happening. The additional data is fetched but is not passed down to the, now, already open dialog.

**Questions**

1. How do I pass the newly found data into the already opened dialog?
2. If not possible, I would assume then that my approach is an anti-pattern, if so, how can I approach this in a way that works as I expect?

Answer (score 1):

Data injection in Material dialogs (I assume you use it ?) is working with `PortalInjector`s : when the modal is being opened, the token is injected into it.

If you wish to send additional data to your dialog, you can't.

You have several solutions to work around that :

- Using a service to share data
- applying your current objet to the function with `b: this.updateSomeData.apply(this)` (although not recommended)
- Adding the function directly into your `DialogComponent` so that it doesn't rely on another component to run a function : the dependency is already loaded into your `DialogComponent`.
- Using static methods to set up your component (also not recommended)
- Load all of your data before opening the dialog
- ...

If you have a hard time to chose the solution, perhaps give us what you are trying to achieve and then we could offer the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using angular material. According to the docs [Here](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api)

open api return Reference to the newly-opened dialog. Hence you can make use of this and change pass the new Values whenever you need.

```
openDialog() {
    let component = this.dialog.open(DialogDataExampleDialog, {
      data: {
        animal: 'panda'
      }
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        component.componentInstance.data.animal = 'lion'
    }, 5000)
  }
```

See it working [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zeln7q?file=app/dialog-data-example.ts). Wait for 5 sec and see the data changing.

Also you can use a shared service and get the job done, Hope this helps.

Comment: Good stuff. This would have never occurred to me even though I know about it. Doesn't look like good code but does what I want. I will accept this one.